# Fixed Place Permutation/Combination

Tags: permutation, combinations

I am looking for a way where I can generated different combination of 4 sets elements in such a manner that every set's element has a fixed place in the final combination:
To explain better my requirement let me give sample of those 4 sets and finally what I am looking for:

Set#1(Street Pre Direction) { N, S }
Set#2(Street Name) {Frankford, Baily}
Set#3(Street Type) {Ave, St}
Set#4(Street Post Direction) {S}

Let me list few expecting combinations:
**N Baily Ave S

S Frankford St S

S Baily Av S

.

.

.**

Now as you can see that every set's element is falling into its place
Pre Direction is in Place 1
Street Name is in Place 2
Streety Type is in Place 3
Street Description is in Place 4

I am looking for the most efficient way to carry out this task, One way to do it is to work at 2 sets at a time like:
Make Combination of Set 1 and Set 2 --> create a new set 5 of resulting combinations
Make Combination of Set 5 and Set 3 --> create a new set 6 of resulting combinations
Make Combination of Set 6 and Set 4 --> This will give me the final combinations

Is there a best way to do this thing? Kindly help. I will prefer C# or Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ David B
What if predirections list is empty, is there a way that we still get the combinations since through your way none cartesian product will be returned.

---

David B here:

```
var query =
  from d in predirections.DefaultIfEmpty()
  from n in names.DefaultIfEmpty()
  from t in types.DefaultIfEmpty()
  from s in postdirections.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new {d, n, t, s};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some linq (c#) that gives you all combinations, it is not "the most efficient way".

```
var query =
  from d in predirections
  from n in names
  from t in types
  from s in postdirections
  select new {d, n, t, s};
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the cartesian product of some sets.  You can do it using nested for loops.  Here's the Haskell code, which you didn't ask for.

```
Prelude> [[x,y] | x <- ['1'..'3'], y <- ['A'..'C']]
["1A","1B","1C","2A","2B","2C","3A","3B","3C"]
```